# Grep variable expansion within "find -exec sh -c"

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

I've written a script that loops through word documents to match words within them. Below is an example that works, and finds the number 43. Following that is a script that doesn't work. All I want to do is have the number 43 as a variable at the start of my script, but it doesn't seem to expand properly. Any ideas how I can have 43 as a variable in my script rather than hard coding it?

Script that works:

```
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
docx2txt "$file" 2>/dev/null - | grep -i --color "43" && printf "\033[1;32mFound in ${file}\033[0m\n"
#readlink -f "$file"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Script that doesn't work:

```
scan_var=43
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
docx2txt "$file" 2>/dev/null - | grep -i --color "$scan_var" && printf "\033[1;32mFound in ${file}\033[0m\n"
#readlink -f "$file"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a security perspective, you should be using `export` to expose variables to subprocesses through the environment, not substituting those variables into strings parsed as code (which lends itself to [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection) attacks).

That is:

```
export scan_var=43  ## the **only** change is to this line!

# only modifications to code below are formatting with no functional impact
# ...well, and safer printf use (to not expand format strings in filenames)
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    docx2txt "$file" 2>/dev/null - \
    | grep -i --color "$scan_var" \
    && printf "\033[1;32mFound in %s\033[0m\n" "$file"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: Duh, of course. Single quotes had nothing to do with it.

Comment: I still think your answer was a valuable one, teaching a useful technique -- if you don't plan on undeleting it after editing, I might extend this one to cover the argv approach.

Answer (score 2):

`sh -c` forks a subprocess, where the variable isn't visible, see [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55047786/3266847) for a fix.

Another technique to get a variable into `-exec sh -c` is to use it as a parameter. Consider

```
$ var=43
$ sh -c 'echo "$var"'         # Expands to nothing

$ sh -c 'echo "$1"' sh "$var"  # Gets variable value into sh -c
43
```

Notice that the first parameter for `sh -c` after the command is used as `$0` within `sh -c` (the name of the process).

Applied to your command:

```
scan_var=43
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -exec sh -c '
    scan_var=$1
    shift
    for file do
        echo docx2txt "$file" 2>/dev/null - \
            | grep -i --color "$scan_var" \
            && printf "\033[1;32mFound in ${file}\033[0m\n"
        # readlink -f "$file"
    done
' sh "$scan_var" {} +
```

The value of the first parameter is read into `scan_var` and the parameter then discarded with `shift`.

Answer (score 0):

You are atempting to use a variable inside single quotes.
Adjust the `grep` command line:

```
grep -i --color "'"$scan_var"'" && ...
```

This will close the single-quote from your `find -exec` before `$scan_var` and start a single-quote for the rest of the code.

Comment: Consider the case where `scan_var=$'42$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` -- it can't be safely substituted into code in *any* kind of surrounding quotes. By contrast, passing it through the environment is 100% safe.

Comment: (Benjamin W's answer is *also* safe for all possible values; this is the only one presently available on the question that isn't).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism @CharlesDuffy.